# Unable to upload video using TwitterKit iOS SDK (Bad Request: 400)

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to upload a 250 KB, 500 x 500 video to Twitter using TwitterKit's built in method "uploadMedia";

However I get this 400 error:

```
Domain=TWTRNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=, TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=400, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}, {
NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";
NSLocalizedDescription = "Request failed: bad request (400)";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "";
TWTRNetworkingStatusCode = 400;
}
```

To upload the video I get the NSURL of the local file, convert it to NSData, then call the function with "multipart/form-data" as the content type

```
NSString *path = [finalVideoURL path];
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];

NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:userID];

[client uploadMedia:data contentType:@"multipart/form-data" completion:^(NSString * _Nullable mediaID, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

}];
```

I've tried tons of different things like different video formats, as well as different content-types. Does anyone have an example of this working?

Thank you,
Gabe

Comment: Did you find how to properly use this uploadMedia function?

Comment: I'm having the same issue even now.  Did you solve this issue finally?  I searched around but couldn't find any updates about this issue.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did anyone find any solution?